# How to open newBrowserWindow in a total center of two extended monitors at electron atom

Tags: electron, screen, monitor

How to open newBrowserWindow in a total center of two extended monitors in electron atom ?
Now I can open my electron app on a first monitor or on a second monitor separately, but I can't find solution to open app in a total middle of both screens, or open electron app on a full two monitors extended screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`screen`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/screen.md) API for such purposes. The actual calculation is up to you.

```js
const electron = require('electron')
const { BrowserWindow, app } = electron
const _ = require('lodash')

app.once('ready', () => {
  const { screen } = electron
  let bwBounds = {}
  if (screen.getAllDisplays().length > 1) {
    const d1 = screen.getAllDisplays()[0]
    const d2 = screen.getAllDisplays()[1]
    // bounds calculation from d1 d2
    bwBounds.x = (d1.bounds.x + d2.bounds.x) / 2
    bwBounds.y = (d1.bounds.y + d2.bounds.y) / 2
    bwBounds.width = (d1.bounds.width + d2.bounds.width) / 2
    bwBounds.height = (d1.bounds.height + d2.bounds.height) / 2
    // numbers rounded
    bwBounds = _.mapValues(bwBounds, Math.round)
  }
  const bw = new BrowserWindow({
    // enables _resize_ larger than screen
    enableLargerThanScreen: true
  })
  // resize
  if (!_.isEmpty(bwBounds)) bw.setBounds(bwBounds)
})
```

Comment: Your answer still run app only in one screen ( screen1 or screen2 ), please see example at the link, what I have and what I want [here](https://pastebin.com/6wcKfZWm)

Comment: @AgrisČerevko r u sure? For me the created BrowserWindow overlaps with both display. (win10, electron 2.0.2). BTW, add that example in your question's body instead sharing by link, plz